# Is https retained on relative form action URLs?

Tags: html, url, forms, ssl

Consider a page with a form that is visited via https.  If the form action has a relative URL to the form page, is the https protocol retained?

Ex: you visit:

```
https://example.com/cart.html
```

which contains the form tag:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="SubmitOrder.aspx" id="form1">
```

Is the form submitted via https or http?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, because it's a relative path.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, relative paths always stay. Direct URLs are only needed when switching between http/https or vice versa.

Comment: Or when switching hosts or ports.

Answer (score 2):

In short: Yes, the same URL scheme is used.

In detail: Relative URLs are resolved to absolute ones on the base of the current document’s URL. So if your URL is a `https` URL and you don’t specify the URL scheme (obviously because otherwise you would have an absolute URL), the resolved URL uses the same URL scheme as the base URL.

Answer (score 1):

It should retain the https part.