# ColdFusion Relative Form Action Switching From HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: html, forms, http, coldfusion, https

So recently we had a bunch of legacy applications moved to a new server and not surprisingly a bunch of stuff blew up.

This particular issue has to do with a CF 8 application.  Users are hitting a page on HTTPS (e.g. https://www.mysite.com/default.cfm).  The form action is something like "/action.cfm?variable=true".  When the form is submitted though the page they land on is http://www.mysite.com/action.cfm?variable=true.  Switching from HTTPS to HTTP is causing sessions to be lost.

One possible problem that I think may be causing it is that none of the CF 8 hot fixes got applied to the new server yet and the JVM version also needs to be updated.  Could either of these be the culprit?  We're planning on addressing both in the next few days but I'd like to know if it's just wishful thinking that it will fix the problem.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: If you are specifying a relative URL in the form like that then it should keep the same protocol. Are you sure there is not a `cflocation` or some other redirect that is happening when the form is submitted? I don't think patching or upgrading the JVM is going to change the behavior.

Comment: There is a CF location in one spot that is also using a relative URL.  I thought this may be the culprit but I went in to dev tools and rewrote the action on the form to be an absolute URL, with HTTPS, and then it behaves correctly.

Comment: It must be something else in your code. The HTML form action should not behave that way - [reference 1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1589361/1636917), [reference 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3209137/1636917). Do you have a `<base>` tag in your page? [Base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)